# new DOM creation when launching opentok video , make impossible to push button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i'm currently developing a mobile application with opentok 2.2 beta new version , and angularJs 1.2.9

i got a problem with the video conversation, when i initialize it, i can still push the button to terminate , but when the other user is connected , a new DOM is created with the video and i can't access (can't push it) anymore the button to terminate the conversation

The things i don't understand , it's that i  did what the opentok Doc told me , i used the **"insertmode:replace"** , but it seems to do work like the **"append"** mode who create a child of the targeted element...

source : *http://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/subscribe-stream/js/*    : **-> Subscribing to a stream**

**the Javascript :**

```
    var publisher = TB.initPublisher($scope.apiKey, 'layoutContainer');
    var session = TB.initSession($scope.apiKey, $scope.sessionId);
    session.on({
        streamCreated: function (event) {
            var subscriberProperties = {insertMode: "replace"};
            session.subscribe(event.stream, 'layoutContainer', subscriberProperties, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                }
            });
    });
    session.connect($scope.token, function () {
        session.publish(publisher);
    })
```

**here the HTML :**

```
 <div class="main_view">
   <div id="layoutContainer"></div>

   <div id="boutonLayout">
       <div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 5% ;height: 70px;">
          <form name="sessionVideo" ng-submit="endCall()" novalidate>
              <div style="text-align:right; width:300px; bottom:80px;">
                  <input id="endCall"
                         style="width:150px; font-size: 14px; height:50px; font-weight: bold; background-color: dodgerblue"
                       type="submit"
                       value="terminer l'appel"/>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**css :**

```
#layoutContainer {
 background-color: #e3e3e3;
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;left:5%;right:5%;bottom:20%;
}

#boutonLayout {
 position:absolute;
 top:80%;left:5%;right:5%;bottom:0%;
}

.main_view{
position: absolute;
top:5%; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
background-color: #FDFDFD;
}
```

thanks for reading , hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

okai , i found the solution , the opentok plugin for cordova didn't implement the function "insertmode" yet....

so you can just put the position to relative to the object you want to be with the new child

ie :

```
#boutonLayout {
 position:relative;
 top:80%;left:5%;right:5%;bottom:0%;
}
```

that's my temporary solution waiting the release of this feature

have a good day